# Correct Way to connect 5 car batteries in parallel

Tags: batteries, parallel, interconnect

My RV (which I bought used) came with 3 Deep Cycle Marine batteries in Parallel. A previous owner added wiring inside the coach for 2 more batteries, but they were not there when I purchased the coach.
The 3 batteries needed replacing, so I purchased 5 27DC batteries. The wiring is shown in the below figure. When I connected these, I got some burned wires. I've replaced them with 3/0 wire on the 3 batteries.

The 3 batteries in the upper left are in a compartment in the chassis of the RV. The other 2 are inside the rig in a closet (where a washer/dryer used to be.
[image: Battery Wiring]

Is there a "best practice" to connect all of these in parallel?

I have looked in to a disconnect switch for the battery bank. They appear to be connected to the Negative. Why the negative terminal?

Comment: Were all the batteries charged before connecting them together?

Comment: They were all brand new. Purchased at the same time and never used before installing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the disconnect switch in the positive lead from the battery bank.  The negative terminal is normally connected to the vehicle frame.

For marine use (and good practice anywhere) the American Boat and Yacht Council recommends a fuse within 7 inches of the battery positive terminal - a bit difficult to arrange when you have so many batteries.

I'd suggest two fuses - one for each group of batteries.

Comment: 7 inches?! That'll be tough. Will it matter if one fuse blows first?

Comment: @ScottieH: The fuses should be a high enough rating that they won't blow in normal operation, but a short to the the vehicle frame should blow them, and hopefully prevent a fire.

Comment: Something like this? https://powerwerx.com/dual-mrbf-terminal-fuse-block-300a

Comment: @ScottieH:  You should have one fuse close to each battery bank - you need a Blu Sea 5191 single fuse block at each battery.  (some people would suggest a fuse on each indiviual battery, but I thin that's a bit much...)

Comment: Found 'em. IT looks Awesome & Easy to Install.